# Count selected checkboxes using jquery.

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to count the number of checkboxes that have been checked. But, the count remains 0 even though I click. Here is my code.

```
<div>
<input type="checkbox" class="category1"></input>
<input type="checkbox" class="category1"></input>
<input type="checkbox" class="category1"></input>
<input type="checkbox" class="category1"></input>
</div>
```

and my JS code is..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $(".category1").click(function(){

                var category1Count = $('.category1 :checked').size();
                console.log(category1Count);
            });


        });
    </script>
```

There must be a simple mistake. Not able to find out. Where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: `.category1 :checked` means, select all selected elements that are **descendants** of `.category1` elements. Instead you want `.category1:checked` which means "select all `.category1` elements which are also selected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **length** property instead of **size()** method

Check the following code..

```
$('.category1:checked').length;
```

Check the following image..
[image]

***And check the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ne3YZ/)***

Comment: Why should `.length` work instead of `.size()`? They are both the same.

Comment: (of course `.length` is preferred and `.size` is deprecated, but that doesn't explain why `.size()` doesn't work. Hence the problem is likely something else.)

Comment: @Rahul: `.size()` works, your selector is wrong. It's correct in this answer, but not explained. See my comment to your question.

Answer (score 3):

Use `length` to get the count of elements. You also do not need space between `.category1` and `:checked`

> The .size() method is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. Use the .length
>   property instead.
>
> The .size() method is functionally equivalent to the .length
>   property; however, the .length property is preferred because it does
>   not have the overhead of a function call. [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/size/).

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W2nS9/1/)**

```
var category1Count = $('.category1:checked').length;
```

Answer (score 2):

size() and length both works but in the OP code he was just placing a space which causing not to work.

`$('.category1 :checked')` should be this: `$('.category1:checked')`

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ne3YZ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var category1Count = $("input:checkbox:checked").length;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".category1").click(function(){
          console.log($(":checkbox").filter(":checked").size());              
      });
 });
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NikhilButani/67QEL/)